# Extraction of POSIXlt component runs fine in R 3.4.4, but errors in R 3.5.0. Why?

Tags: r, datetime, posixlt

**1) R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)**

```
my.timedate <- as.POSIXlt('2016-01-01 16:00:00')  
# print(attributes(my.timedate))  
print(my.timedate[['hour']])  

[1] 16
```

**2) R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)**

```
my.timedate <- as.POSIXlt('2016-01-01 16:00:00')  
# print(attributes(my.timedate))  
print(my.timedate[['hour']])
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: What is the output for `unclass(my.timedate)` in 3.5.0

Answer (score 9):

I *think* that is a known change in R 3.5.0 where the list elements of a `POSIXlt` need to be unpackaged explicitly.  Using R 3.5.0:

```
edd@rob:~$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:3.5.0 \
               R -q -e 'print(unclass(as.POSIXlt("2016-01-01 16:00:00")[["hour"]])'
> print(unclass(as.POSIXlt("2016-01-01 16:00:00"))[["hour"]])
[1] 16
> 
> 
edd@rob:~$
```

whereas with R 3.4.* one does not need the `unclass()` as you showed:

```
edd@rob:~$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:3.4.3 \
               R -q -e 'print(as.POSIXlt("2016-01-01 16:00:00")[["hour"]])'
> print(as.POSIXlt("2016-01-01 16:00:00")[["hour"]])
[1] 16
> 
> 
edd@rob:~$
```

I don't find a corresponding NEWS file entry though so not entirely sure if it is on purpose...

*Edit:* As others have noted, the corresponding NEWS entry is the somewhat opaque

> ```
> * Single components of "POSIXlt" objects can now be extracted and
>   replaced via [ indexing with 2 indices.
> ```

Comment: The original example can be found in "Processing and Analyzing Financial Data with R" by Marcelo S. Perlin, 2017 (pages 108-109). I simply replicated it (with errors) in R 3.5.0. This is a simple example code. What is the best way to ensure that a complex code written in one version of R does not suddenly begin to return errors in a newer version, due to changes that maybe opaque?

Comment: That is a very valid question, and an important. Base R is usually exemplary about ensuring compatibility but there are rare times when a change has to be made. Note though that you can also use accessors such as `hour() ` in `data.table`. They offer a layer of indirection.

Answer (score 5):

See `?DateTimeClasses` (same as `?as.POSIXlt`):

> As from R 3.5.0, one can extract and replace single components via `[` indexing with two indices

See also similar description in [R NEWS CHANGES IN R 3.5.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html).

Thus:

```
my.timedate[1, "hour"]
# [1] 16

# or leave the i index empty to select a component
# from all date-times in a vector 
as.POSIXlt(c('2016-01-01 16:00:00', '2016-01-01 17:00:00'))[ , "hour"]
# [1] 16 17
```

---

See also **Examples** in the help text.

Answer (score 5):

From `?POSIXlt`:

> As from R 3.5.0, one can extract and replace single components via `[` indexing with two indices (see the examples).

The example is a little opaque, but shows the idea:

> ```
> leapS[1 : 5, "year"]
> ```

If you look at the source, though, you can see what's happening:

```r
`[.POSIXlt`
#> function (x, i, j, drop = TRUE) 
#> {
#>     if (missing(j)) {
#>         .POSIXlt(lapply(X = unclass(x), FUN = "[", i, drop = drop), 
#>             attr(x, "tzone"), oldClass(x))
#>     }
#>     else {
#>         unclass(x)[[j]][i]
#>     }
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x7fbdb4d24f60>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

It is using `i` to subset `unclass(x)`, where `x` is the POSIXlt object. So with R 3.5.0, you use `[` and preface the part of the datetime you want with the index of the datetime in the vector:

```r
my.timedate <- as.POSIXlt('2016-01-01 16:00:00')

my.timedate[1, 'hour']
#> [1] 16

as.POSIXlt(seq(my.timedate, by = 'hour', length.out = 10))[2:5, 'hour']
#> [1] 17 18 19 20
```

Note that `$` subsetting still works as usual:

```r
my.timedate$hour
#> [1] 16
```